# Full screen background image with centered text and scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, responsive-design, background-image

I'm making a one page website with a full screen background image that also scrolls.

[Here's an example page](http://www.taniarascia.com/image-scroll/).

[Here's a git repo with all the code](https://github.com/taniarascia/image-scroll).

On a desktop screen, this code will always work perfectly.

HTML:

```
<section class="test">
  <header>
  Horizontally and vertically centered text
  </header>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.test {
  background: url('img.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 20px 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  top: 38%;
  transform: translateY(-38%);
}
```

38% works for this case particularly, most likely because I have a navbar above it. I know 50% would make more sense, maybe someone can explain that further.

In any case, despite it looking fine on my resized screen, if I actually look at it on mobile it looks awful. To fix that issue, I changed the code to add `@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {}` around the header, so there's no code applied on smaller screens. This is the current code.

It looks fine, but it feels hacky and imprecise, so I'm wondering if there's a much better way to do this that I'm missing. Obviously I can't used `position: fixed` because the site involves scroll; if the site was one full screen image without scroll, I could use fixed positioning.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understood you correctly, but if you are trying to archive a vertical alignment of the text you could use flexbox layout for example.

```
article {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 90vh; //100vh - navbar height 
}
```